# How to move multiple articles from one Gnus group to another?

Tags: gnus, email

<kbd>B m</kbd> ([`gnus-summary-move-article`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Mail-Group-Commands.html#Mail-Group-Commands)) in Gnus [summary mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Summary-Buffer.html) allows to move an article from one [group](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Group-Buffer.html#Group-Buffer) to another. But how do I move not a single, but tens or hundreds of articles from one group to another? Using keyboard macros seems unidiomatic and error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [process marks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Setting-Process-Marks.html#Setting-Process-Marks). Mark all articles you need to move from one group to another. For example, you can simply mark all articles you want to move by manually pressing <kbd>#</kbd> (`gnus-summary-mark-as-processable`).

Then after you marked all needed articles, press <kbd>B m</kbd> and move all articles to the group you want.