# Gnus: Moving multiple articles to a single group

Tags: gnus

My question is similar to [How to move multiple articles from one Gnus group to another?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19360/how-to-move-multiple-articles-from-one-gnus-group-to-another). However the answer given there didn't work for me.

Suppose I want to move multiple articles in a summary region to another group (I am accessing emails over IMAP), I mark all the articles in a region with `M P r` to get a `#` mark. Now I do `M-& B m` to move the process marked articles and specify the target group.

Unfortunately, Gnus is asking me the target group for each and every article which is annoying. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Looks like I was unnecessarily pressing `M-&` (i.e. `M-S-&`) before `B m` as specified in the below pasted last paragraph of https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Process_002fPrefix.html#Process_002fPrefix

`Many commands do not use the process/prefix convention. All commands that do explicitly say so in this manual. To apply the process/prefix convention to commands that do not use it, you can use the M-& command. For instance, to mark all the articles in the group as expirable, you could say M P b M-& E.`

While commands like expire article (`E`) will need the above `M-&` prefix, the commands like `B m` (`gnus-summary-move-article`) will honor process marks and will move all marked articles to the target buffer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you mean by `M-& B m`?

In my Emacs config, `M-&` (with shift) is bound to `async-shell-command`, and I think that's a default key binding. If you meant `M-7 B m` (without shift), then you asked Emacs to run `gnus-summary-move-article` seven times. It would make sense that it prompts you for a destination seven times.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up question. I was referring to the very last paragraph of https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Process_002fPrefix.html#Process_002fPrefix which asked user to press `M-&` (i.e. `M-S-&`) to run a command if it doesn't support a process mark (like E). I found that in my case the `B m` command supports process marks and doesn't need `M-&` to process all marked articles.

Comment: In Gnus buffers, `M-&` is bound to `gnus-summary-universal-argument`. This answer, which should have been just a comment, is totally off the mark.